# npm & git - Generating artifacts on commit

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, build

I see a lot of npm modules that require a build/compilation step have a `dist/` folder in their repo. Do the authors run the build step before committing manually or is this automated on commit, if so how?

Example repos:

https://github.com/se-panfilov/vue-notifications

https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2

https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-progressbar

Is it common to run the build step manually before a commit? How is this enforced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build step is usually *not* part of a commit but rather before publishing to npm. This can be automated in different ways, for example in a `prepublish` script.

Comment: Right this is what i was thinking as well, but in the projects i shared there is no such script. Is it safe to assume they are running the build step manually?

Comment: Yes most likely.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Manually run the build commands, commit to git, and also publish to npm.
2. Commit to git, a CI server picks it up, builds and publishes to npm.
3. Use git hooks to build before each commit.
4. Add the build commands to `postInstall` step in `package.json`, this builds the module **after** a user has `npm` installed it.